# Overriding default behaviour of dictionaries in Swift to ignore zero values?

Tags: swift, dictionary, overriding

I want to create a data type that acts like a Dictionary but ignores any keys whose value is zero, e.g. consider a hypothetical example:

```
typealias SpecialDict = Dictionary<String,Int>
let testA: SpecialDict = ["a":1, "b":4, "c":0]
let testB: SpecialDict = ["a":1, "b":4]
testA == testB // should evaluate as true
```

I'm not sure whether it'd be better to:

- override == to give this behaviour, at a cost every time two dictionaries are compared
- override updateValue(_:forKey:) so that whenever we try to set a value to 0, it just removes the corresponding key from the dictionary instead (preferred)
- try a different data type altogether

Alternatively, a way to create a dictionary with a fixed list of keys (i.e. you cannot add or remove keys, just change their values) would also work.

Comment: It may not help with your use case, but you might be able to take advantage of the fact that assigning `nil` to a dictionary value deletes it: `var d = ["a":1,"b":2,"c":3];d["c"]=nil;println(d) // no "c" entry`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the easiest way is to create your own `struct`, which behaves the way as you want. I would do something like this:

```
struct MyDict {

    private var dictionary = [String: Int]()

    subscript(key: String) -> Int? {
        get {
            return dictionary[key]
        }
        set {
            if newValue! != 0 {
                dictionary[key] = newValue
            } else {
                dictionary.removeValueForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this struct is **NOT** a dictionary, so you have to implement every function that you need.

Comment: This wouldn't work for, e.g., `var test: MyDict = ["a":1, "b":4]` and then `test["b"]=0`, because then you'd be left with `test` unchanged using your solution, which is not the desired behaviour. I might try a struct-based solution like this, but I was hoping for something simpler or more idiomatic/elegant.

Comment: @Matthew I updated my answer according to it. As far as I know, you cannot override global functions (like ==), because the result would be ambiguous, and dictionary is a struct, so it cannot be a superclass to override one of its methods, this is why I suggested this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not sure I understand not being able to override == though? e.g. a trivial example like `func == (lhs: SpecialDict, rhs: SpecialDict) -> Bool { return true }` works. I know you can't superclass a dictionary, but I didn't realise you couldn't extend/override it either. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew what you have done here is overridden `==` for ALL string-to-int dictionaries, not just special dictionaries.  `typealias` is what it sounds – an alias, not a different type.

Comment: That is true, but with that implementation you does not override anything, because the signature of == for dictionaries is looks like this: 

    func ==<Key : Hashable, Value>(lhs: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>, rhs: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>) -> Bool (you can see here: http://swiftdoc.org/operator/eqeq/ ), so basically you just created a new function, but does not override anything.

Comment: @DánielNagy strictly speaking, he has overridden `==`, just with a higher priority than the existing dictionary `==` because `String` is more specialized than `K: Equatable`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity are you sure? (I'm definitely not:D) shouldn't the requiment for overriding something is the same signature? Isn't that is rather shadowing the original implementation? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dániel overloading, rather than overriding, I guess, but these are quite loose terms... Shadowing suggests the old version is now unreachable, but it is still there for types that match it but not the `[String:Int]`-specific version.